# angular 4 FileReader onloadend not getting called on IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, filereader

I am trying to read data from an excel file. The following code w stopped working on IE11, I don't know why? When I put the console logs, I see onloadend is not getting triggered. Please let me know any ways to fix this.

```
private myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
changeListener($event): void {
    readThis($event.target);
  }

readThis(inputValue: any): void {
    const file: File = inputValue.files[0];
 public test: String[] = [];
if (fileType === 'xlsx') {
      console.log(this.myReader);
      this.myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
        /* read workbook */
        const bstr: string = this.myReader.result;
        const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });
        /* grab first sheet */
        const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
        const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];
          this.data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 });         
          this.data.forEach(eachline => {
             if (eachline[0] !== undefined) {
              test.push(eachline[0]) ;
            }
            }
          });
      };
      this.myReader.readAsBinaryString(file);      
    }
}
```

Comment: its the problem using readAsBinaryString on IE. I fixed using readAsArrayBuffer using the link below.
https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/wiki/Reading-XLSX-from-FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()

Comment: Have you tries using `onload` instead of `onloadend`?